# ConTeXt: Round corner for fieldset with title

Tags: context, framed, metapost, context-lmtx

## Background

I'm looking to stylize an HTML fieldset-like environment to would allow consecutive "concurrent" sections to appear in the document.

Using version 2023.07.18 22:07.

## Output

Example output:

[image: Fieldset]

## Code

Here's what I have so far:

```tex
\startuseMPgraphic{GraphicConcurrent}
  begingroup;
    string legend;

    picture title;
    picture border;
    picture bg;

    numeric tw;
    numeric th;

    legend := \MPstring{1};

    title := nullpicture;
    border := nullpicture;
    bg := textext( "\strut " & legend );

    tw := xpart lrcorner bg - xpart llcorner bg;
    th := ypart ulcorner bg - ypart llcorner bg;

    addto title also image(
      fill unitsquare
        xysized (tw + 8, th)
        shifted ulcorner multipars[1]
        shifted 28 right
        shifted 8 down
        withcolor white;
        
      draw
        textext.drt( legend )
        shifted ulcorner multipars[1]
        shifted 32 right
        shifted 3 down;
    );

    addto border also image(
      for i = 1 upto nofmultipars:
        draw
          llcorner multipars[i] --
          ulcorner multipars[i] shifted 8 down ..
          ulcorner multipars[i] shifted 8 right --
          urcorner multipars[i]
          withpen pencircle scaled 0.75 withcolor black;
      endfor; 
    );

    draw image(
      draw border;
      draw title;
    );
  endgroup;
\stopuseMPgraphic

\definetextbackground[TextConcurrentFrame][
  mp=GraphicConcurrent,
  frame=off,
  topoffset=1em,
  leftoffset=1em,
  location=paragraph,
]

\definestartstop[concurrent][
  before={%
    \blank[big]%
    \setMPtext{1}{Terminal Berth 5}
    \startTextConcurrentFrame%
  },
  after={\stopTextConcurrentFrame\blank[big]},
]

\starttext
  \startconcurrent
    \dorecurse{7}{\input knuth}
  \stopconcurrent

  \input ward

  \startconcurrent
    \dorecurse{7}{\input knuth}
  \stopconcurrent
\stoptext
```

This produces simple borders around the text, spanning pages as desired:

[image: Fieldset]

## Problem

Using `cornered` to round the corner seems to require a cycle, which isn't always needed.

## Question

How would you round the corner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the rounded corners bit, you could be more creative with the `if` statement:

```
begingroup;
  for i = 1 upto nofmultipars:
    draw llcorner multipars[i] --
      if multikind[i] = "first":
        ulcorner multipars[i] shifted 8 down ..
        ulcorner multipars[i] shifted 8 right --
        urcorner multipars[i]
      else:
        ulcorner multipars[i]
      fi
    withpen pencircle scaled 0.75 withcolor black;
  endfor; 
endgroup;
```

(*not tested*)

Comment: Do we need to add `(boxlineradius, 0){down}` in there to get the curve? The shifts make a straight line like a dog-eared page.

Comment: Well I have not tested it but the `..` should give a curve.  You could use `boxlineradius` instead of the arbitrary `8` that I used, eg `ulcorner multipars[i] shifted (0, -boxlineradius)` instead of `shifted 8 down`.

Comment: `shifted 8 down` == `shifted (0, -8)` by the way -- just easier to read for me.